# strange behavior when subtracting numbers

Tags: javascript, floating-point, applescript

When I use this code in Applescript (or another language):

```
set var1 to "0.00"
set var2 to "50.86"
set var3 to "1335.56"
set var4 to "60.72"
set netto to "1447.14"

set sub_totaal to var1 + var2 + var3 + var4
set sub_dif to sub_totaal - netto
```

The answer is: `-2.27373675443232E-13`

Why?

Comment: Floating-point back in action!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken

Answer (score 0):

Not all fractional decimal values have an exact (base-2) binary representation. Most programming languages are obliged to honor the host's floating-point arithmetic implementation, which means the normal rules for commutative and associative arithmetic do not hold.

Notice that even the final decimal value: [`1447.14`](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=049052052055046049052) cannot be represented *exactly* as an (IEEE-754) floating-point value.

Regardless of what language you use, it's crucial to be aware of these limitations. The analysis of floating-point precision / range errors is almost a separate field in itself.

Comment: Hi Brett, thanks. I solved it this way: set sub_dif to ((sub_totaal * 100) - (netto * 100)) / 100

Comment: @user2553579 - I suspect you just 'got lucky', in that scaling has resulted in a [loss of significant digits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance). It may have worked in this case, but it's worth maintaining an awareness of these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to do precision math you can use unix tools. For example one such tool is "bc". So just send your calculations to the command line tools.

```
set var1 to "0.00"
set var2 to "50.86"
set var3 to "1335.56"
set var4 to "60.72"
set netto to "1447.14"

set cmd to var1 & "+" & var2 & "+" & var3 & "+" & var4
set sub_total to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of cmd & " | bc"

set cmd to sub_total & "-" & netto
set sub_dif to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of cmd & " | bc"

return {sub_total, sub_dif} --{"1447.14", "0"}
```

Comment: Thanks! An other solution is to make a string of cmd.